# Options to control (fast switch) a 12V LED DC with MCU - mosfets vs. relays vs. SSR vs. mosfet relays vs. something else?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, relay, dc, 12v

(Newbie alert) I have a 12V 3A light that I want to control in a ~12V DC circuit (lead acid battery, stator coil). The light shares a common ground with every other light unit in the circuit. I was looking into options how to control it with Arduino or similar microcontroller. I found few options and I have few doubts.

- nMOS: most examples and cases have them connected between the load and ground. Since all the light loads in my circuit are sharing the same ground, this looks problematic - would wiring a separate ground for that one controlled light with nMOS be a safe practice?
- relays: I'm aware that these are the simplest solution, but since I'm doing this as a practice project, I would prefer a device that bit more "new tech" so to speak
- solid state relays: I've looked on few catalogues and it seems most of SSRs are for controlling AC loads, and few of DC variants I've found are limited to 1A or some low number.
- mosfet relays: I found this on Omron website ([link](https://components.omron.com/solutions/relays/mos-fet-relay)) but my level of understanding finds it too convoluted and there seems to be lack of youtube videos about these devices, can anyone enlighten me how do these devices work?

Comment: 12V 3A is a good candidate for a MOSFET.  N-channel shouldn't be a problem; at some point everything gets connected to ground but if you share a schematic of your system, that would clear a lot up however.  There are certainly DC SSRs available for high current, you might just be looking at signal relays.

Comment: It depends of your budget. Electromagnetic relay or MOSFET relay (considerably SSR too) essential than you need galvanic isolation. Sometimes it is preferable because auto environment is very tough.

Comment: @vir - https://i.imgur.com/cn0hK9c.jpg as you can see here, a lot of things share same ground, blue wire is for the light I wish to control. My idea was to remove the common ground from that load and put the ground on a separate point on the chassis. Not sure if there are some precautions on doing this, in terms of interference with other "grounds" on that same chassis.

Comment: @user263983 yeah I'm reading the specs on [this fet relay](https://components.omron.com/product-detail?partNumber=G3VM-61CR1%2FG3VM-61FR1) - load voltage 60V and continuous load 5A, should be more than enough. I don't care about budget, few bucks up or down, it's a one off project for learning so I'll be ok if some components are bit pricey, I don't mind that. But I can't see how would it work when controlled by a Arduino, logic level.

Comment: It is optocoupler. Current nominal 10 mA. Can be driven straight from MCU output with resistor. For  resistor nominal calculation consider drop voltage on internal LED.

Comment: You should go further from that page to datasheet.

Comment: This is basically the same question you asked recently regarding controlling headlights of a motorbike. Did I not give you specific solutions? This question is more obscure so the answers will be less focussed. Again, the solution boils down to a relay or an automotive high side driver.

Comment: hey @Kartman ! I know I know I'm asking the same questions again, I think I'm overwhelmed by the challenges and problems I read online on the original idea of using a nMOS for low side switching and the common ground situation in my case. And there's a lot of choices that lead to analysis paralysis I guess. I found [this Ardu board with power switches](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/24v_shield_btt6030/) and I'm really considering buying it.  It seems to be the exact thing I need.

Comment: For your application, Kawasaki would probably use a relay. When you talk of ‘fast’ - do you want to flash the headlights faster than the indicators?